# Problem with K&R exercise 1.22, some lines go beyond wrap limit

Tags: c

I'm reading the K&R book (The C Programming Language) and I'm having a hard time finding out what is wrong with my code for exercise 1.22:

> Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more
>   shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th column of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WRAP 40       // maximum output line length limit
#define MAXLINE 1000  // maximum input line length limit

int getLine(char line[]);

/* test getLine fuction */
int main(void) {
    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = getLine(line)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}

/* getLine: read input and save it in line array; return its length.
 * folds long input lines into two or more shorter lines
 * after the last non-blank character that occurs before
 * the n-th column of input. */
int getLine(char line[]) {
    int c, i, j, count;

    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (i < MAXLINE && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (count == WRAP) {
            for (j = i; j >= 0 && line[j] != ' '; --j)
                ;

            // this line is to demonstrate the current c, j, i and count values
            printf("c: -%c-, j: %d, i: %d, count: %d\n", c, j, i, count);

            if (line[j] == ' ')
                line[j] = '\n';
            else {
                line[i] = '\n';
                ++i;
            }

            line[i] = c;
            ++i;
            count = 0;

        } else {
            line[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }

        ++count;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

For example, I use a simple lorem ipsum pragraph to test it:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

The result is:

```
c: -p-, j: 39, i: 40, count: 40
c: - -, j: 74, i: 80, count: 40
c: -d-, j: 119, i: 120, count: 40
c: - -, j: 157, i: 160, count: 40
c: -n-, j: 198, i: 200, count: 40
c: -b-, j: 239, i: 240, count: 40
c: -u-, j: 275, i: 280, count: 40
c: - -, j: 309, i: 320, count: 40
c: -a-, j: 355, i: 360, count: 40
c: -i-, j: 398, i: 400, count: 40
c: -i-, j: 434, i: 440, count: 40
c: -e-, j: 476, i: 480, count: 40
c: -i-, j: 518, i: 520, count: 40
c: -f-, j: 558, i: 560, count: 40
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
an unknown printer took a galley of type
and scrambled it to make a type specimen
book. It has survived not only five
centuries, but also the leap into
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
with the release of Letraset sheets
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
recently with desktop publishing software
like Aldus PageMaker including versions
of Lorem Ipsum.
```

As you can see, some lines go beyond 40 characters, for example the 3rd line is 44 characters long, but the count variable does not catch it! What is wrong with it?

Comment: you check if `count`, the amount of characters read on that line, is equal to `WRAP`, which is `40`.  if it is, then you do whatever you do in that block and then proceed to reset `count` at the end of the `if(count == WRAP)` block.

Comment: @Tau Yes, That is what I did. How should it be then?

Comment: If you see that you have more characters on a line than you had originally intended there to be, you could increase `WRAP` to, let's say, 50.  If that doesn't fix the problem then you may need to rethink how your method works.

Comment: `int getLine(char line[])` is irreparable here.  When a wrap needs to occur along space/tab boundaries, in essence, a number of characters need to be "put back" and saved for the next line.  You need a new approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset `count = 0` when you inserted a `'\n'` somewhere. This may be correct if you inserted it at `line[i]`. If you inserted it at `line[j]` (with `j!=i`) you must take into account the number of characters after `line[j]` up to `line[i]`. So if there are e.g. 10 characters after `line[j]` you might have to set `count = 10` instead of 0. (Of course you have to calculate the number.)

I'm not sure if everything will always work as expected because in

```
for (j = i; j >= 0 && line[j] != ' '; --j)
            ;
```

you compare `line[i]` but have not yet written the character `c` to this position. (You do this after the checks for wrapping.)

If there is no space in the last `WRAP` characters, this loop will even run over a `'\n'` you inserted before and insert `'\n'` for a space before this.
Try entering a long line like
`12345 12345 12345 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb` (all in one line).

Comment: Yes, True. I came into realize that the code is a mess :). I'll rewrite it with another approach.